# Can a dynamic value (register or memory) be used with RET when cleaning the stack?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, return, calling-convention

I use NASM, and I have a question about the `ret` instruction. I know that I should specify after the `ret` how many variables I sent to the stack, but how can I do that dynamically? I tried:

```
ret eax
```

and

```
ret dword[var]
```

but neither of these work. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: No. For varargs we normally use _cdecl_ convention, and then you can free the arguments in the caller by adjusting `esp` which does work dynamically. If you really-really want to do it for stdcall, you can pop the return address then remove the arguments and jump to the address (or put it back and `ret`)

Comment: Of course those don't work.  [`ret` is documented in the manual](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/RET.html) as taking either no operand or taking an imm16.

Answer (score 3):

There is no opcode that could do that, the only available one requires the number to be a constant.

You could theoretically pop the return value into a register, then adjust the stack pointer based on your dynamic value, push the return address and `RET` but it's a bit complicated.

What is the reason why you need to do this? Usually any values in the stack before the return address belong to the calling function and it's their job to handle them.

Comment: There is no reason to loop.

Comment: @Jester Ach, true. Stupid me.

Comment: I need to calculate a polynom but I don't know the leangth of it.

Comment: @RoiAvram What about self-modifying code? Should work on a Real Mode OS. Ugly but does what is required.

Comment: @RoiAvram You should pass a pointer and a length for example. Or use cdecl.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not know the number of bytes that were pushed onto the stack when your function was called *as an assembly-time constant*, then you need to use a different calling convention. Specifically, one that is *caller* clean-up, rather than *callee* clean-up.

In order for the callee to clean up, it needs to know exactly how many bytes the caller pushed onto the stack. When you are dealing with normal parameterized functions, this is not a problem. The function signature tells you precise what types of arguments it takes, and how many. For example:

```
int FrobWidget(void* pWidget, int timesToFrob);
```

assuming that pointers are 64 bits and ints are 32 bits on a hypothetical architecture, this function knows that the caller pushed 12 bytes onto the stack before calling it. Therefore, the `FrobWidget` function would end with `ret 12`, popping those 12 bytes off the stack and returning to the caller.

The most common callee clean-up convention is known as `stdcall`, and it is used heavily in Windows programming. Nearly all of the Windows API functions are `stdcall`. The reasons are mostly historical, but can still matter today if you are a micro-optimization enthusiast. Basically, the idea is that a function gets called many more times than it is defined, so having the function itself clean up the stack will result in a lot less code than having each caller clean up the stack after each call to the function. Given this fact, and the *de facto* platform standard, I use `stdcall` as the default calling convention for all Windows programs I write.

However, as you have seen (and Sami has already pointed out), there is no way to *dynamically* clean up the stack. The [`ret` instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_280.html) comes in two forms (ignoring far and near variants): one that takes no arguments, and one that takes an immediate argument. You can't use an enregistered value or a memory operand. This is why the function has to know how many bytes to pop off the stack as an assembly-time constant.

So as cool as callee clean-up conventions are, they do have this significant limitation, which manifests itself in the inability to use this calling convention for *variadic* functions. Variadic functions are those with indefinite [arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity); in simple terms, they take a variable number of arguments, and the precise number is not known at assembly-time. In fact, the actual number and types of the arguments is known only by the *caller*. This is why variadic functions require a caller clean-up convention.

The standard example of a variadic function in C is `printf`:

```
int printf(const char* pFormat, ...);
```

Unlike the previous case, the function signature doesn't tell us anything definitive. I mean, it has a friggin' ellipsis! The function takes as many arguments as the caller decides to pass. This means only the caller knows how many bytes need to be popped from the stack in order to clean it up after the call. So the `printf` function simply returns with `ret`, and lets the caller handle the cleanup.

The most common caller clean-up convention is known as `cdecl` because it is the traditional C calling convention. It is widely used on Linux and other non-Windows platforms, and it is used on Windows where it *must* be used (*i.e.*, for variadic functions, like the [`wsprintf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550.aspx) API).

Both of these calling conventions (`stdcall` and `cdecl`) pass arguments on the stack right-to-left, so the principal difference is whether the callee or the caller clean up the stack. Having the callee clean up the stack requires that it knows at assembly-time exactly how many bytes were passed on the stack. If this is not know, you *must* use a caller clean-up convention like `cdecl`.